# How to prepare the data from openweather API for leaflet velocify wind map?

Tags: leaflet, vite, react-leaflet

Currently, I am implementing the wind map with **leaflet-velocity https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-velocity **and using the data from https://onaci.github.io/leaflet-velocity/wind-global.json. But the data look strange for me. Is there any way to convert the weather data of OpenWeather API for all cities in specific country because those two format are totally different.

#### Supported Structure of Data

```
[
    {
        "header": {
          "discipline": 0,
          "disciplineName": "Meteorological products",
          "gribEdition": 2,
          "gribLength": 76420,
          "center": 7,
          "centerName": "US National Weather Service - NCEP(WMC)",
          "subcenter": 0,
          "refTime": "2016-04-30T06:00:00.000Z",
          "significanceOfRT": 1,
          "significanceOfRTName": "Start of forecast",
          "productStatus": 0,
          "productStatusName": "Operational products",
          "productType": 1,
          "productTypeName": "Forecast products",
          "productDefinitionTemplate": 0,
          "productDefinitionTemplateName": "Analysis/forecast at horizontal level/layer at a point in time",
          "parameterCategory": 2,
          "parameterCategoryName": "Momentum",
          "parameterNumber": 2,
          "parameterNumberName": "U-component_of_wind",
          "parameterUnit": "m.s-1",
          "genProcessType": 2,
          "genProcessTypeName": "Forecast",
          "forecastTime": 0,
          "surface1Type": 103,
          "surface1TypeName": "Specified height level above ground",
          "surface1Value": 10.0,
          "surface2Type": 255,
          "surface2TypeName": "Missing",
          "surface2Value": 0.0,
          "gridDefinitionTemplate": 0,
          "gridDefinitionTemplateName": "Latitude_Longitude",
          "numberPoints": 65160,
          "shape": 6,
          "shapeName": "Earth spherical with radius of 6,371,229.0 m",
          "gridUnits": "degrees",
          "resolution": 48,
          "winds": "true",
          "scanMode": 0,
          "nx": 360,
          "ny": 181,
          "basicAngle": 0,
          "subDivisions": 0,
          "lo1": 0.0,
          "la1": 90.0,
          "lo2": 359.0,
          "la2": -90.0,
          "dx": 1.0,
          "dy": 1.0
        },
        "data": [
          4.54,
          4.52,
          4.49,
          4.47,
          4.44,
          4.41,
          4.38
        ]
    }
]
```

#### Open Weather Map Data

```
[
  {
    "coord": {
        "lon": 106.461,
        "lat": 11.0895
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 804,
            "main": "Clouds",
            "description": "overcast clouds",
            "icon": "04n"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 300.07,
        "feels_like": 304.38,
        "temp_min": 300.07,
        "temp_max": 300.07,
        "pressure": 1005,
        "humidity": 97,
        "sea_level": 1005,
        "grnd_level": 1003
    },
    "visibility": 5928,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 2.79,
        "deg": 202,
        "gust": 9.37
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 86
    },
    "dt": 1693763130,
    "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 9314,
        "country": "VN",
        "sunrise": 1693781064,
        "sunset": 1693825374
    },
    "timezone": 25200,
    "id": 1584661,
    "name": "Cu Chi",
    "cod": 200
  }
]
```

Convert Open Weather Map API Data of cities in specific country to compatible leaflet velocity data